# Pset2 Need help encrypting words

Tags: vigenere

Vigenere is encrypting the message incorrectly for example if the key is "hello" and the message is hello, the encrypted text is now "eipsv" when it should be "hello".

I would really appreciate any tips on fixing this bug.

```
    string message = GetString();
    int m = strlen(message);
    int i = 0;

      if(isalpha(message[i]))
      {
     for(int j = 0; j < n; i++)
    {
     key[j] = tolower(key[j]) - 97;
     j++;

      for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
       {
            char c = message[i];

              if (islower(c))
                {
                    c = (((c - 'a' + key[j%n])%26) +'a');
                    j++;
                    printf("%c", c);
                }
              if (isupper (c))
                    {
                        c = (((c - 'A' + key[j%n])%26) +'A');
                        j++;
                        printf("%c", c);
                        }
              else if (!isupper(c) && !islower(c))
                    {
                     printf("%c", c);
                     j++;
                    }  
      } 
      }
    }
   printf("\n");  
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think that "hello" + "hello" = "hello"?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a mistake on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a handful of changes:

Your first loop to convert the key to values of 0 - 25 should be in a separate loop from the encoding loop.  Convert the key, and then move on to the encoding loop.

In the encoding loop, you will need two incrementers, "i" and "j", both of which need to be reinitialized to 0 in your FOR ( ...;...;... ) line.  You can't reuse "j" from your key conversion loop because it is out of scope.

Remove j++ after your printf() line from your ELSE IF statement in encoding loop.  You do not increment "j" if a letter isn't encoded.

By the way, once you update your program and run it through check50, you will find several error-check errors because you have some error conditions to check that I don't see in your current code.  But, it should encode correctly with the above changes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the keyword "hello" would encode your message "hello" as follows:

```
h -> (shift 7) -> o 
e -> (shift 4) -> i 
l -> (shift 11) -> w
l -> (shift 11) -> w 
0 -> (shift 14) -> c
```

So, **the result should be "oiwwc".**

Comment: Yes thank you, this is what it should read as an encrypted text. But how can I fix this as I have included what should happen if the letter is lowercase, uppercase, and otherwise and increased the counter in all of them?